# How can I show the inputAccessoryView in this view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I have a function in my controller I call

```
private func toggleLauncher() {
    let launcher = CommentsLauncher()
    launcher.showLauncher()
}
```

This essentially adds a view on top of the current view, with a semi transparent background.

I'd like to then render a custom `inputAccessoryView` at the bottom of the newly added view.

```
class CommentsLauncher: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    }

    func showLauncher() {
         if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            window.addSubview(view)
        }
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            let containerView = UIView()
            containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
            containerView.backgroundColor = .purple
            return containerView
        }
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

All that happens though is the semi transparent background is visible but I see no `inputAccessoryView` added to the view also and I am unsure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CommentsLauncher never become the first responder in the code you provided. A UIResponder's inputAccessoryView is displayed when the responder becomes first responder.

Change your showLauncher method to something like this:

```
func showLauncher() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        window.addSubview(view)
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

And you should see the input accessory view.

Comment: Ah! Yes! That would make complete sense! Thank you so much :)